# How to write to database all cache in Odoo environment?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm doing a test where I need to imitate the onchange behavior, so:

```
with self.env.do_in_onchange():
    self.onefield = "blahblah"
```

But when one exits the with block, that data is not written to DB. I'm looking for some kind of `self.env.cache.write_to_db()`. Do you know of any?

Comment: Please tag Odoo version. I assume this solution could change and so version info on the tag would be crucial. -- as we can already see by the comment from @MouTio below the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

To write a record's cache:

```
self.write(self._convert_to_write(self._cache))
```

To write all the environment's cache:

```
models = dict()
for field, cache in self.env.cache.iteritems():
    for id_, value in cache.iteritems():
        models.setdefault(field.model_name, list())
        models[field.model_name].append(id_)

for name, ids in models.iteritems():
    for record in self.env[name].browse(ids):
        record.write(record._convert_to_write(record._cache))
```

Comment: Just for information: The part of writing a record's cache didn't work for me in Odoo 9. Instead of that, I executed this and worked fine:

self.env.cr.commit()