# odoo cache force save

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am developing some tests which, as setup, requires to write some test records, while in executing calls a method which perform a `self.env.cr.execute` of a sql SELECT, but records written in the setup remain into the cache thus the execute returns nothing (I also checked that a `browse(<id>)` returns the record, while `select([('id','=',<id>)])` which is itself based on `execute`, doesn't.

I tried

```
models = dict()
for field, cache in self.env.cache.iteritems():
    for id_, value in cache.iteritems():
        models.setdefault(field.model_name, list())
        models[field.model_name].append(id_)

for name, ids in models.iteritems():
    for record in self.env[name].browse(ids):
        record.write(record._convert_to_write(record._cache))
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254792/how-to-write-to-database-all-cache-in-odoo-environment), and I also tried to commit (`self.env.cr.commit`) just after the setup, but result is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using python? If so can you tag it as such?

Comment: I did not tag it as python because it is completely not python-dependant, but openerp. Even a python genius who doesn't know openerp could fix this :(

Comment: Yeah, I meant that tags really affect who views the question. Not a lot of people are subscribed to the openerp or odoo-8 tags, while the python tag is popular. At least your question will get more exposure that way. Some of them might know the solution.

Comment: I think the Python tag should be removed. Knowing Python does not mean you know or understand the logic behind odoo-8.  Also, this is not a Python issue. It just so happens that the logic is written in Python .. but a Python developer that does not know Odoo will not have the answer.